# "The file MyGraph.ps hasn’t been created from MyGraph.dot yet."

Tags: graphics

My basic first test of graphviz integration doesn't work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphviz}

\begin{document}

\digraph[scale=0.5]{MyGraph}{rankdir=LR; a->b; b->c}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
```

[image]

I seem to be compiling it [in accordance with the documentation](https://github.com/mprentice/GraphViz-sty) so what's wrong?

Also, if I run `pdflatex` again

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .ps.
```

...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
```

See section 5 in the manual.

Avoid the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

\begin{document}

\digraph[scale=0.5]{MyGraph}{rankdir=LR; a->b; b->c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I just compiled exactly your code and still have the same placeholder output as before. `dot` is installed and working as a separate program. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @spraff Can you look in the log file and report the version of `graphviz` you're using?

Comment: Ah, I left out the -shell-escape option this time